# Is it possible to upgrade image of an existing container?

Tags: docker

I want to upgrade the image where an existing container runs. After executing `docker pull`, I got the latest image. But the container still run on the older image. Is it possible to make an existing container to run on latest image? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at this time, but there's an open [feature request](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2733) to support this use case.